# doorkeeper auth flow not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, doorkeeper

I am trying to perform the oauth2 flow as described by https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Interacting-as-an-OAuth-client-with-Doorkeeper#writing-a-raw-oauth-client, but I get a 401 when 
I try to retrieve the access token.  Here is what I am doing

1) click the authorize button on the application as seen here [image]
2) I authorize the application on the next screen and I'm given a url of the form `chromiumapp.org/?code=eb775dba8811f605c672a0aac8472972eabaae87446ac957e2b71c57b0b10e6e`

3) Given this code I perform

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:3000/oauth/token -d '{ 
  "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
  "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET, 
  "redirect_uri": "https://galaiojniedmogfplghkjnmcfnlbpbpg.chromiumapp.org/", 
  "grant_type": "authorization_code", 
  "code": "eb775dba8811f605c672a0aac8472972eabaae87446ac957e2b71c57b0b10e6e" 
}`
```

However this returns `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."}`

Is there some part of the flow that I'm missing or is there something incorrect in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the wiki I linked above, but incase others come across this question, per the rfc, the parameters on the token request must be form urlencoded.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:3000/oauth/token
  -F "client_id=CLIENT_ID"
  -F "client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET" 
  -F "redirect_uri=https://galaiojniedmogfplghkjnmcfnlbpbpg.chromiumapp.org/"
  -F "grant_type=authorization_code"
  -F "code=eb775dba8811f605c672a0aac8472972eabaae87446ac957e2b71c57b0b10e6e"
```